# Hidden cells also get changed when I try to change a filtered cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with huge datasets in Microsoft Excel – thousands of rows and twenty columns. The columns are like *product*, *type*, *price*, *market* etc.

Suppose I want to change market or price of some products into one category.  Suppose there are fifteen such products whose market should be changed from *North* to *South*.

First I sorted those products. After filtering it, I type *South* for one of those products (which is first in row) and then drag it, but all the hidden cells also change to South. I want to change the market or price only for those fifteen products.

Answer (score 3):

And alternative to dragging the contents of a cell, you can Copy/Paste:

1. Copy the first cell containing `South`.
2. Select the cells of the 15 products to be changed.
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Or <kbd>F5</kbd>) then click <kbd>Special...</kbd>
4. Select "Visible cells only".
5. Paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Note: And alternate to steps 3 & 4 is to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> when pressing <kbd>;</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working properly as you said. Now my tasks will be much easier. One thing I must  ask you that previously, I never had have such issue in my entire life. This is peculiar. I have just joined a new organization and here I am facing this particular issue. Can you tell me that what is the reason behind this as previously I never faced this issue...??? is there settings to be fixed to avoid this issue.

Comment: @user252137 I'm not sure. I have this issue now and again with excel files now and again but haven't been able to reproduce it on sample data :( My current hypothesis is that it more often happens when there is a big amount of data and Excel sort of cannot perform the operation on a filtered set (it's much easier on an unfiltered set).