# How to turn on or off editing invisible cells when filtering?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I filter out a row in excel, if I edit the entire range (including the cell that is filtered out), only visible cells get edited. When my boss does this on his computer, the entire range gets edited, including what is hidden... There must be an option somewhere to change this.

A more visual example:
Here are some cells:

```
     A 
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1
```

If I filter column A to only keep the 1s, here is what I get:

```
     A 
1    1
4    1
```

I now select everything (the 1s) and I type ZZZ and press CTRL + ENTER to edit the entire range. I now unhide everything, here is my result:

```
     A 
1    ZZZ
2    0
3    0
4    ZZZ
```

Here is my boss's result:

```
     A 
1    ZZZ
2    ZZZ
3    ZZZ
4    ZZZ
```

What setting do I have to edit to make it so that we have the same answer?

Comment: I found someone with the same problem but no solution. I don't want to have to press F5, select visible cells. I don't have to do it on my machine, it does it automatically. Only my boss's machine has this issue. https://superuser.com/questions/642178/hidden-cells-also-get-changed-when-i-try-to-change-a-filtered-cell

Answer (score 1):

This could be a difference on how these cells are hidden. With your sample data, try the following:

***First:***

- Use a filter on your range to only see the `1`s
- Select range `A2:A5` including the hidden cells
- Type `ZZZ` and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Remove filter to show all cells, result:

[image]

***Now:***

- Select rows 3 and 4 and hide them
- Select range `A2:A5` including the hidden cells
- Type `ZZZ` and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Unhide the hidden rows, result:

[image]

So the conclusion might be that your boss is approaching "hidden" cells differently than you are doing. A more in depth comparison between filtered and hidden cells is made [here](https://wmfexcel.com/2015/06/13/hidden-rows-vs-filtered-rows/).

***Direct solution:***

Make sure to, when the range `A2:A5` is selected, you hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> key combination to deselect all invisible cells in your selection before you start making changes.

Comment: My boss's computer is being used by me, I am running the exact same filtering operation (as your first demonstration) but his excel behaves like hidden cells rather than filtered cells. Super strange. I am going to assign CTRL + ENTER to a vba macro that does ALT + ., CTRL + ENTER.

Comment: @sorinlonescu, which version of Excel is running on your boss pc, and what version on the other pcs?

Comment: Office 365 on all PCs

Comment: @SorinIonescu, can I delete this answer? As is this does not seem to be answering your question.